# Store a value in a session and pass to next view in iPhone?

Tags: xcode4.2

In my App I am retrieving a value from WCF service URL by using XML Parsing and Iam storing those values in a NSString and NSMutableArray.Now I want to pass those values from one view to next view on a button click and they have to be displayed in a label in nextView  .How can I achieve it?i.e How to store the values in a session in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? If so, you can use the `prepareForSegue()` call as in this example.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURVIEW"]) {
        YOURVIEWCONTROLLER *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.var1  = @"HELLO 1";
        destViewController.var2  = @"HELLO 2";
    }
}
```